# SOCKS5 auth 0x84

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, socks, rfc

I am trying to implement a Socks5 client in C#, everything is working fine, I implemented all of the required auth methods.

It worked fine with a local Socks5 proxy, but then I tried to connect to a public server and it wanted to auth using a method with the number `0x84`, which is in the range of private methods ([X'80' to X'FE' RESERVED FOR PRIVATE METHODS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt)).

Then I tried a few other servers and they all wanted this method.
Now I am wondering where I can find the specifications for this, since I was unable to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the public socks server was running version 4 and not, as advertised version 5.
And i had a bug in making shure the version is equal to 5.